# How can I remove Linux and Install windows XP from a usb?

Tags: linux, windows-xp, boot, windows-installation, liveusb

I have a Sony Viao laptop and **only** **Kali linux** is installed on it. I want to remove it from my hard disk and replace it with WindowsXP.

I created a windows XP 32 bit USB(8 GB) by using Rufus and tried booting it on the laptop.

Only when I press F10 key then I can see that the machine freezes on a black screen and nothing happens, or else it skips to GRUB and starts loading Kali Linux. I have changed the boot order to USB in 1st priority, 2nd to Hard Disk and 3rd to CD/DVD Drive.Still I have to press the F10 key.

Is there a way of doing it by a bootable DOS usb? 
I tried multiple times but unable to succeed. Any method will be helpful.

**Please Help**

Answer (score 0):

I use the official [Windows USB/DVD Download Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/windows-usb-dvd-download-tool) which will copy your WinXP cd to a USB and make it bootable.